# ProvidedIn in Router service and forroot in RouterModule

Tags: angular

According to [doc](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern) in `Angular` tutorial, if you define a `Service` with `providedIn` with root, you don't need to have `forroot` pattern because there will only be one `instance` for the whole app. In Angular source code, I see the `Router` service has already been defined with providedIn "root", then why does `RouterModule` still provide this forRoot static method. Is this for configuration purpose?

I tried searching for answers online but haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Because the app.module is your root module. Otherwise, routing won't work correctly with the redirects to your home.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? So forroot is to make sure redirect works as expected? Not to make sure the router service is a single instance?